# Session values in HttpContext.Current.Session in C# set and get

Tags: c#, session, get, set

I have static class called **MailContainer** in a *MasterPage*.

In **MailContainer** Class, I have defined properties for get /set like below.

```
public static class MailContainer
{
    public static string TheObjectPropertyEmail
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"] = value;
        }
     } 
}
```

When I try to assign an value like below on **Default.aspx.cs** with *MasterPage*.

```
MailContainer.TheObjectPropertyEmail = reader["Email"].ToString();
```

Its throwing the below exception.

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

on this line :

```
return HttpContext.Current.Session["TheObjectPropertyEmail"].ToString();
```

How do i fix this ?

**Edit #01**

```
public void Aut()
{
    sql = @String.Format(" SELECT * FROM doTable ");
    sql += String.Format(" WHERE ");
    sql += String.Format(" UPPER(user) IN (?); ");

    using (OdbcConnection myConnectionString =
        new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, myConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                if (username != null)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", username.ToString().ToUpper());
                    command.Connection.Open();

                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                MailContainer.TheObjectPropertyEmail = reader["Email"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
                     }   
                 }                         
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8) here. This an HttpContext only available in web related projects like

1. WebForms for asp .net
2. WebApi
3. MVC

Now depending on the lifecycle, the HttpContext is or isn't initiallized. We need to know more about your specific exmample on when you call and set, get the session for us to help you.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you I have edit my first question, please can you help me ?

Comment: Where are you doing the assignment? In the constructor?

Comment: The assignment it's on Default.aspx.cs with MasterPage. Please see **Edit #01** in my first question